# Set Memory Limit in htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am working on WordPress. I need to increase the memory, so I added the following line to my .htaccess file

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

php_value memory_limit 64M
```

my sample php page

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

but it throws the 500 internal server error. what is the problem here..

Comment: on which page is it throwing 500 error?

Comment: is your PHP runs in CGI mode instead or as a Apache module (mod_php)?

Comment: Have u tried changing in php.ini file  `memory_limit = 64M`

Comment: Closed as off topic, wondering why?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

In your *.htaccess* you can add:

**PHP 5.x**

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_value memory_limit 64M
</IfModule>
```

**PHP 7.x**

```
<IfModule mod_php7.c>
    php_value memory_limit 64M
</IfModule>
```

If page breaks again, then you are using PHP as mod_php in apache, but error is due to something else.

If page does not break, then you are using PHP as CGI module and therefore cannot use php values - in the link I've provided might be solution but I'm not sure you will be able to apply it.

Read more on http://support.tigertech.net/php-value

Comment: If you are using PHP 7, then the code should look like this:
`<IfModule mod_php7.c>
php_value memory_limit 900M
</IfModule>`

Comment: @Carol-Theodor Pelu . I did not understand why 900M ?

Comment: @MindRoasterMir its not about 900M, it was about using `mod_php7.c` for PHP7... answer is already edited, so this comment now looks odd.

Comment: just found this, but I don't see the difference between the two statements. although it could be my old eyes. What am I missing (I get that the ifModule statements are an example of how to check versions.)