# Can't change memory_limit local value in phpinfo

Tags: php

I can't change the local value of `memmory_limit`, I tried to fix in `.htaccess` but it's not working. When I fix `memory_limit` in `php.ini` only master value changed.

[image]

Comment: [check this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12172844/4248328)

Comment: Also you have to restart your server (xampp/wampp/Lamp) what ever you used.

Comment: I have restarted my server but it does not work.

Comment: https://davidwalsh.name/increase-php-memory-limit-ini_set

Comment: Sorry I'm a newbie, where can I put `ini_set('memory_limit','256M');`. Thanks.

Comment: I have placed `ini_set('memory_limit','256M');` in my script but it does not work.

Comment: `PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 65536 bytes) in /home/admin/web/voisenhansgrohe.com/public_html/wp-includes/pomo/mo.php on line 273, referer: http://voisenhansgrohe.com/wp-admin/theme-editor.php?file=header.php&theme=ShopperWooTheme&scrollto=480` this is error log

Answer (score 1):

Add this to beginning of your php page

```
<?php ini_set('memory_limit','256M'); ?>
```

For unlimited memory limit set -1 in memory_limit variable

```
<?php ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');  ?>
```

If you are using wordpress

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '1024M'); in wp-config.php
```

Comment: It's not working for me. PHP error log `PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 65536 bytes) in /home/admin/web/voisenhansgrohe.com/public_html/wp-includes/pomo/mo.php on line 272, referer: http://voisenhansgrohe.com/wp-admin/theme-editor.php?file=header.php&theme=ShopperWooTheme&scrollto=480`

Comment: Try to increase the size more.  by giving "-1".

Comment: I tried `define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '1024M');` but it does not work. This problem is local value of `memory_limit` always at `32M`. I can't change it. When I setup in `php.ini` or `.htaccess` `wp-config` only master value of `memory_limit` changed.

Answer (score 1):

that was helpful for me.
just add to the virtual host config file:

```
php_admin_value memory_limit 1024M
```

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for this problem. Check all files Apache config. One of theme override setup of php.ini.
If you use vestacp: `/home/[user]/conf/web/httpd.conf` or `/usr/local/vesta/data/templates/web/httpd`
Thanks all for help!